# why is part of my mesh not affected by subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: mesh, edges, faces, subdivision-surface

[image]

Only the right side seems to be affected.

Here is a blend file if you need it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zESOunpfijGMY_71UO04QfNuUIA8QNhl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Probably there are duplicated verts. Try to remove them. Select everything and hit alt+m and choose merge by distance.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.